# The requested URL was not found on the server razorpay API

Tags: php, laravel, razorpay

I have below code in my web

```
$api_key = env('rzpKey');
$api_secret = env('rzpSecret');
$accountId = env('rzpAccountId');
$api = new Api($api_key, $api_secret);
$rzp = $api->payment->fetch($request->razorpay_payment_id);
// ..captured payment.. and then below is for transfer
$transfer = $rzp->transfer(array('transfers' => [ ['account' => $accountId, 'amount' => $request->totalAmount * 100, 'currency' => 'INR']]));
```

When I submit the form and make transfer it showing the below error and the error points to this ($transfer) line

> Razorpay\Api\Errors\BadRequestError
> The requested URL was not found on the server.

But in my local this problem is not there and I can transfer successfully!

I saw this [answer](https://github.com/razorpay/razorpay-node/issues/148#issuecomment-721222779) but doesn't know whether this related to my problem or not

Thanks in advance